# Getting "an illegal memory access was encountered" for the simplest CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, linux, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to learn CUDA programming on my GeForce RTX 2060 GPU on Ubuntu 22.04 using CUDA V12.2.128.

When I compile the following code and try to run it,

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

#define CUDACHECK(E) if (E != cudaSuccess) \
    { \
        std::cerr << "Fatal error [line " << __LINE__ << "]: " << cudaGetErrorString(E) << ".\n"; \
        std::abort(); \
    }

#define ASSERT(B) if (!(B)) \
    { \
        std::cerr << "Fatal error: test failed in line " << __LINE__ << ".\n"; \
        std::abort(); \
    }

__global__ void fill(float* x, const std::size_t& size, const float& value)
{
    const auto tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < size)
    {
        x[tid] = value;
    }
}


int main()
{
    // allocate device data
    const auto size = std::size_t{10000};
    auto* xD = static_cast<float*>(nullptr);
    CUDACHECK(cudaMalloc(&xD, size * sizeof(float)));
    ASSERT(xD != nullptr);
    
    // run fill kernel
    const auto fill_value = static_cast<float>(-1.0);
    fill<<<1,1>>>(xD, size, fill_value);
    CUDACHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    
    // <--- control doesn't get past here!
    
    // copy to host
    //auto* xH = reinterpret_cast<float*>(std::malloc(size * sizeof(float)));
    //ASSERT(xH != nullptr);
    //CUDACHECK(cudaMemcpy(xH, xD, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    
    //constexpr auto tol = std::is_same<float, float>::value ? static_cast<float>(1E-5) : static_cast<float>(1E-10);
    //for (auto ii = std::size_t{}; ii < size; ++ii)
    //{
    //    ASSERT(std::fabs(fill_value - xH[ii]) < tol);
    //}
    
    // free
    CUDACHECK(cudaFree(reinterpret_cast<void*>(xD)));
    //std::free(xH);
    
    // tests have been passed
    std::cout << "Tests passed! Hallo, CUDA world!" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Fatal error [line 42]: an illegal memory access was encountered.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Then, I used the compute-sanitizer with `--tool memcheck` and got the following output:

```
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 8 bytes
=========     at 0x20 in fill(float *, const unsigned long &, const float &)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7ffc902b1f30 is out of bounds
=========     and is 639.439.150.385 bytes after the nearest allocation at 0x7f67aea00000 of size 512 bytes
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame: [0x32e950]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:libcudart_static_4d8b33a106dceb3c07a56e26de61f2d53bb62a68 [0x1093e]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:cudaLaunchKernel [0x70b4e]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:cudaError cudaLaunchKernel<char>(char const*, dim3, dim3, void**, unsigned long, CUstream_st*) [0xb235]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:__device_stub__Z4fillPfRKmRKf(float*, unsigned long const*, float const*) [0xb094]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:fill(float*, unsigned long const&, float const&) [0xb0f7]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:main [0xadaa]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:__libc_start_call_main [0x29d90]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:../csu/libc-start.c:379:__libc_start_main [0x29e40]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:_start [0xab15]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
========= 
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 719) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame: [0x47e786]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:cudaDeviceSynchronize [0x48a64]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:main [0xadaf]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:__libc_start_call_main [0x29d90]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:../csu/libc-start.c:379:__libc_start_main [0x29e40]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:_start [0xab15]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
========= 
Fatal error [line 42]: ========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 719) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame: [0x47e786]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:cudaDeviceSynchronize [0x48a64]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:main [0xadfb]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
=========     Host Frame:../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58:__libc_start_call_main [0x29d90]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:../csu/libc-start.c:379:__libc_start_main [0x29e40]
=========                in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame:_start [0xab15]
=========                in /home/nitin/Documents/code/gpu/device/./hw_cuda
========= 
unspecified launch failure.
========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
========= Target application returned an error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors
```

**Questions**:

1. What could be the cause of this error?
2. How can I proceed with debugging it?

I will gladly provide more information when asked for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `auto* xD = static_cast<float*>(nullptr);` is a very complicated way of saying `float* xD = nullptr;`

Comment: Similarly with `const auto fill_value = static_cast<float>(-1.0);` which could be replaced by `constexpr float fill_value = -1.0;`

Comment: And `reinterpret_cast<void*>(xD)` is likely not needed either, as C++ allows all pointers to objects to be implicitly converted to `void*`. It's the opposite conversion which isn't implicit.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Following the _always auto_ style, I like to see my types on the right hand side of the `=`. Regarding the `reinterpret_cast`, I like to make my casts explicit instead of using the C-style casting.

Comment: You cannot pass kernel arguments by reference unless they are in memory accessible by both host and device, which is not the case for ordinary stack variables

Comment: Regarding the `reinterpret_cast<void*>(xD)` cast, the cast isn't needed at all. Plain `xD` should work just fine. You complicate things too much. And if you want `auto` always (which isn't always possible) then `constexpr auto fill_value = -1.0f;` should work just fine. There's no need to explicitly mention the type if you want to use type-deduction. That' just makes your code overly verbose, harder to read and maintain. And you're not even consistent when it comes to your type deduction. Sometimes you use object-construction syntax and other times you use casting. Pick one, be consistent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Even if you don't mention the cast at all, it'll still be a cast because `float*` is not the same type as `void*`. And having the cast shows you that you're swapping pointer types, which can be handy while debugging. Regarding `constexpr auto fill_value = -1.0f;`, my code is coming from a heavily templatized source, where I would actually have `constexpr auto fill_value = static_cast<Treal_t>(-1.0);`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the object-construction syntax, as you call it, is what I use to initialize any aggregate type which is not a pointer. But you're absolutely otherwise right, I should be more consistent with that.

Comment: A cast is an *explicit* conversion. The compiler is allowed to do some conversions anyway. Doing an explicit cast when the compiler will do that conversion for you anyway is just a waste of time to write the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude We often write useless things in code for readability. Some find it unnecessary, others may find it very useful. Like I said, it may be handy to notice that a certain pointer type is being treated as a _different_ one. A `reinterpret_cast` may be overkill, perhaps a (yet non-existent) keyword to highlight implicit conversions could be a better substitute there.

Answer (score 1):

After @AbatorAbetor mentioned it in a comment, I was able to go back to my code to verify that passing references to automatic variables causes this behaviour. The required correction is:

```
__global__ void fill(float* x, const std::size_t size, const float value)
```

Thank you very much for your help.